# Jquery add tr to last but one row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample Code

```
`<table>  
    <tr>    
<td> first column </td>    
</tr>  
<tr id ="addRow">   
<td><input type="button" id="add_button" name="add" value="Add" /></td>   
</tr>   
 </table>
`
```

Now when i click this Add button it should add tr before this row i.e

```
`<table>  
<tr>   
 <td> first column </td>    
</tr>  
<tr>    
 <td> some content </td>     
</tr> 
<tr id ="addRow">   
<td><input type="button" id="add_button" name="add" value="Add" />   
</td>    
</tr>   
 </table>
`
```

so the next time i click Add button it has to  be

```
`<table>   
<tr>  
 <td> first column </td>   
 </tr>  
<tr>   
<td> some content </td>  
 </tr> 
<tr>   
<td> some content </td>    
</tr>
<tr id ="addRow">   
<td><input type="button" id="add_button" name="add" value="Add" /> </td>   
</tr>   
 </table>
`
```

How is this done?? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function () {
$('#add_button').click(function () {
    $('<tr><td>Some content</td></tr>').insertBefore('#addRow');

});

}):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#add_button").click(function(){
    $('<tr><td/></tr>').insertBefore('#addRow');
});
```

Comment: just .before('#addRow'); instead of .insertBefore('#addRow'); should be enough.